# String.Format numbers in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an an Exception: Input string was not in a correct format.
When I format the phone number string

```
 @String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", @Double.Parse(@item.PhoneNumber))
```

If I hardcode the phone number it works:

```
   @String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", @Double.Parse("1231111111"))
```

or

```
   @String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", 1231111111)
```

Why is it failing when I grab the value from the model?

I want to display as: (123) 456-7890

Comment: Stop with the @ signs. Try `@String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Double.Parse(item.PhoneNumber))`. EDIT: Wait, why are you parsing to a `double` and then string formatting? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: `@item.PhoneNumber`doesn't parse to a double? What is the value of the variable when it fails?

Comment: I removed the other @ signs. Still doesnt work. The item.PhoneNumber is a string. If I dont use Double.Parse, the error is gonne but the string is not formatted. If I use int.Pars() I get Exception: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

Comment: why are you parsing a phone number to an int?

Comment: what is the value of `item.PhoneNumber`? Why do you parse it to a double instead of as a long/Int64?

Comment: @ro-E because if I dont the error is gone but the string is not formatted. If there is a proper way please share.

Comment: if it fails when grabbing the property from the model, what is the value of `item.PhoneNumber`? is there a non-numeric character present? is the value null? tbh conversions like this in the view is frowned upon (even considered an antipattern), it should be done within the controller (or wherever the viewmodel is populated).

Comment: @user1666620 the value is a string "1231111111" coming from DB as nvarchar(max)

Comment: if you check the event viewer, is an exception being thrown? what do you see when you load the page?

Comment: @user1666620 the reason I am doing in a view is because in the controller when I use linq-to-entity (to generate the list)  String.Format not recognized the method

Comment: you should really consider using a viewmodel and working with that rather than returning the table to a view.

Comment: @user1666620 Is there a way to use  String.Format  in LINQ to Entities to format the string ?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a line of code with @, everything after that is C# code. There's no need to continue adding @ signs.

@String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Double.Parse(item.PhoneNumber))

On the other hand, try to use View Models so you don't need to parse objects in the view. It's much better if you do that in the Controller. Your views are gonna be cleaner.

Comment: I removed the other @ signs and I still get the error message.

Comment: Maybe Double.Parse is the problem. What's the type of item.PhoneNumber?

Comment: the reason I am doing in a view is because in the controller when I use linq-to-entity (to generate the list) String.Format not recognized the method. is there another way I can format in the controller and just pass the value to the view?

Comment: Once you have your business objects in the controller, create a View Model then send it to your view. It will make your views much cleaner and it will give you more flexility (how would you handle different phone formats in the view?).